# Blob Download from Azure returns empty

Tags: python, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

My sensor data are stored in an Azure Blob Storage in an hierarchic structure:
First level: location
Second Level: Date
third Level: Time

So if my containername is "edge" the sensor data are stored unter `edge/location1/2021-07-09/07-00/`

Within these folders the sensor data are stored in json files. So from [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-science-process/explore-data-blob) I adapted the code as follows

```python
import json
import pandas as pd
import keyring
import os

STORAGEACCOUNTURL= "https://<mystorageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net"
STORAGEACCOUNTKEY= keyring.get_password('<name>', '<username>')
LOCALFILENAME= os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'test_blob', 'blobstorage.txt')
CONTAINERNAME= "edge"
BLOBNAME= 'location1/2021-07-09/07-00/'
    
#download from blob
t1=time.time()
blob_service_client_instance = BlobServiceClient(account_url=STORAGEACCOUNTURL, 
credential=STORAGEACCOUNTKEY)
blob_client_instance = blob_service_client_instance.get_blob_client(CONTAINERNAME, BLOBNAME, 
snapshot=None)
with open(LOCALFILENAME, "wb") as my_blob:
    blob_data = blob_client_instance.download_blob()
    blob_data.readinto(my_blob)
t2=time.time()
print(("It takes %s seconds to download "+BLOBNAME) % (t2 - t1))
```

The connection seems to work, if I set the BLOBNAME to non-existing blobs I get an BlobNotFound error if I try to download that blob, and I can use the `blob_service_client_instance.list_containers()` to retrieve existing containers etc.

But the download always retrieves empty results. Any idea, why (and yes, of course: There are existing JSON-Files in these blobs)?

Comment: Are you sure `location1/2021-07-09/07-00/` is the name of the blob and not the blob prefix?

Comment: No, I'm not sure about it. But it doesn't make a difference if I put `CONTAINERNAME = "edge/location1/2021-07-09"` and `BLOBNAME = "07-00"` Within the "07-00" folder are the stored JSON Files